# Stepper Angular material custom configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, stepper

I would like to configure my stepper from angular material like this :

When I click on a step, the state toggle between validated or not validated. And after that, only the next step can be clickable.

So, as long as the step is not validate, I can't click on the next step.

I have no idea how to do this. and I need some help.
I saw something like validators.required but I don't know how to make it like I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview). If the mat-step property `linear` is true, you can not get to the next step else you declare the step as `optional`. NOTE: Use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and use the validators you want

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for stepControl `The top level abstract control of the step.` in combination with linear `Whether the validity of previous steps should be checked or not.` Depending how you design this you could skip stepControl. I find it easier to give each step it's own formControl which will contain the validators and fields and `linear` will make sure form is valid before user can proceeded.

```
@Input()
stepControl: AbstractControlLike
```

E.g

```
<h1>Thing {{ id }}</h1>
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" labelPosition="bottom" linear="true">
  <mat-step label="One" [stepControl]="oneForm">
    <my-one #one></my-one>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Two" [stepControl]="twoForm">
    <my-two #two></my-two>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Three" [stepControl]="threeForm">
    <my-three #three></my-three>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stepper-validate-form-ewtpka?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html